# Disassembled Java class file differs from Source

Tags: java, bin-diffing

While trying to understand a behavior of TestNG I found my self disassembling the .class files. During that, I accidentally noticed that the official binary differs from the one built manually from source and from the source itself.

The reason I disassembled the binaries was just to prove that the binary really lacks local variable tables (and for fun), since I was unable inspecting local variables.

- Project: https://github.com/cbeust/testng.git
- Artifact Version / Tag: 6.11
- Source File: [`TestNG.java`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/6.11/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java) (Official Repository)
- Class File: [`TestNG.class` in testng-6.11.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/6.11/testng-6.11.jar) (repo.maven.apache.org)
- Used JDK: OpenJDK 1.8.0 131

I built the source from the project repository at Tag 6.11. using Gradle.

In the first place I inspected both using `javap -l -p TestNG.class`, writing the output into two separate files and diffing the resulting descriptions. So far so good.

Then, for fun, I disassembled both class files using these commands:

```
javap -c -p /tmp/TestNG.mvn.class > /tmp/TestNG.mvn.java
javap -c -p /tmp/TestNG.mine.class > /tmp/TestNG.mine.java
```

Then I diffed both and accidently found the private field `m_executionListeners` to be missing.

```
--- /tmp/TestNG.mvn.java      2017-06-03 23:12:16.005211337 +0200
+++ /tmp/TestNG.mine.java     2017-06-03 23:12:08.245208191 +0200
@@ -92,6 +92,8 @@

   protected long m_start;

+  private final java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends org.testng.IExecutionListener>, org.testng.IExecutionListener> m_executionListeners;
+
```

(No, its declaration did not just move around, it's gone.)

So I thought it could be some kind of compiler optimization. But it is actually referenced and accessed two times. This is one access:

```
public void addListener(ITestNGListener listener) {
   if (listener == null) {
     return;
   }
   if (listener instanceof ISuiteListener) {
     ISuiteListener suite = (ISuiteListener) listener;
     maybeAddListener(m_suiteListeners, suite.getClass(),  suite);
   }
   // ...
   if (listener instanceof IExecutionListener) {
     IExecutionListener execution = (IExecutionListener) listener;
     maybeAddListener(m_executionListeners, execution.getClass(), execution);
   }
   // ...
 }
```

[See the source](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/6.11/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java#L723)

All other fields that run through the `instanceof` check, type cast and `maybeAddListener()` call are still present.

Am I right, with my conclusion, that the binary has not been built from the (supposed-to-be) related source? Or what it going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the binary does not match the tagged source. It does, however, match the changes made in commit [6cfc6b4a403f8487d9fa96aa3d42db7848c8755a](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/commit/6cfc6b4a403f8487d9fa96aa3d42db7848c8755a), which was made on February 25, one day after the most recent commit tagged 6.11 and before the most recent merge commit in 6.11.

I can only speculate, but it seems likely that their local version of 6.11 includes an extra commit or two that they accidentally left out of the tag on Github.